# Can anyone say what will be the procedure need for visiting visa to come to UK for my cousin?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I'm EU citizen I want to bring my cousin who is working in Muscat for a visit to UK. Can anyone say what will be the procedure to bring him?

Comment: Welcome, it's frustrating when we'd love to help, but you've left out SO much information.  What passport is he on? What citizenship? Is he coming as a visitor for a few days or months? Are you living in the UK, or elsewhere in Europe? Visas are VERY complex and specific to situations, you need to add more detail.

Comment: He is Indian. He got India passport.  He is coming for a week to visit. I'm living in uk .. Please help me

Comment: It's best to edit details into the question, people tend to miss them in the comments.

Comment: Note that getting an visa for UK as an Indian to visit some relatives is an *extremely* common reason for applying for a UK visa. There should be plenty of information on the web for that, including this page, and the UK embassy/consulate website. The only thing that is special here is that your cousin is working in Muskat. The UK embassy website for the embassy closest to Muskat will surely tell if he is able to apply there for a visa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are an EU national living in the UK and want to sponsor your cousin for a short visit.  Your cousin is an Indian national who is working in Oman.

From Paragraph 24 of the rules, your cousin will need an entry clearance.  In order to be successful, he will need to clear all of the points listed in Paragraph 41 of the rules.  See https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/immigration-rules

Your cousin should apply on-line as a GENERAL VISITOR. Near the end of the application, he will answer some questions about making a biometrics appointment at a facility in Oman. Once the appointment is booked, he will see a page of information on what to do next.

If you are lawfully in the UK and have the financial capacity along with an acceptable level of credibility, you can participate in the application process by offering to help.  Because cousins do not have the degree of relationship needed to qualify as family, your cousin will be treated as a FRIEND, and they will need a pretty clear understanding of why you want to do this. For example, do you normally sponsor your cousins in the same way?  What's special about this particular point in time?

With this background information, your cousin should start by opening an account and going through the application rigmarole at http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/oman/